# R.java cannot be saved

Tags: android

I has a android project and I write it in eclipse. It can run but somehow my eclipse cannot work so I make another project in eclipse too and copy the java, android manifest and the layout xml. I have changed everything so it would work.I got error at the R.Java which the error some of my variables are including space in it although I never make variable with space character. I corrected it by change the space with underscore but it changed back and there is still space character. I also tried in android studio and it still happened. What is wrong with it? Here is my R.java. The DT Count cannot be changed to DT_Count although my code in source is DT_Count and some how it changed to DT Count and cannot be changed.

Comment: I don't know why your editing the R file :-\ The R file is auto generated from your project so maybe its in your layout xml. Other words, R is not the original location of the problem.

Comment: You are not supposed to touch your R file.

Comment: tried to clean the project? after editing is done on the source file?

Comment: I has tried it but still not works

Answer (score 0):

Import the project in new workspace , or copy all java and XML file to new workspace , clean the project and bield workspace.  Your R file is auto generated, we never do changes in this file . try once again ...

Comment: That is the exactly things that I do. But I dont know the R.java has variable "DT_Count" change to "DT Count". I tried clean it but it cannot work.